# Как можно рандомно вставить картинки в разные места на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 9 блоков img. Изначально они пустые. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку появилась картинка в один из этих блоков рандомно, потом после клика на эту картинку, картинка исчезает и появляется в другом блоке.

Я создал массив из блоков куда нужно показать картинку и у меня есть переменная (картинка).

Попробовал через `Math.random` ничего не получается, картина всегда показывается в одном и том же месте.

```js
var photo = document.getElementById('imgphoto');

var blocks =[
        document.getElementById('block1'),
        document.getElementById('block2'),
        document.getElementById('block3'),
        document.getElementById('block4'),
        document.getElementById('block5'),
        document.getElementById('block6'),
        document.getElementById('block7'),
        document.getElementById('block8'),
        document.getElementById('block9')
    ];
```

```html
<div id="block1"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
<div id="block2"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
<div id="block3"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
 <div id="block4"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
<div id="block5"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
<div id="block6"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
 <div id="block7"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
<div id="block8"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
<div id="block9"><img src="./img/imgphoto.png" alt="" id="imgphoto" class=""/></div>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ?

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let collection = document.querySelectorAll('.photo');
let url = 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg';

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    const item = collection[i];
    if (item.childElementCount) {
      item.firstChild.remove();
    }
  };
  rndImage();
});

for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  const item = collection[i];
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (item.childElementCount) {
      item.firstChild.remove();
      rndImage();
    }
  });
}

function rndImage() {
  let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(collection.length));
  if (collection[rnd].childElementCount) return false;
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = url;
  collection[rnd].appendChild(img);
};
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<button>Press me</button>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да , спасибо большое!

Comment: А не подскажете как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку когда на другом месте появляется картинка, исчезала предыдущая. То есть должно быть всего одна картинка, я буду использовать setInterval.

Comment: @Kardinal добавил код